# Not able to find element using appium

Tags: automated-testing, appium

I am trying to login in app. using appium but getting following error :

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 59 milliseconds

My code is :

```
public class appi {

public static WebDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "");
    File app = new File(appDir, "myapp.apk");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
    capabilities.setCapability("device", "Android Emulator");
   // capabilities.setSerial("192.168.xx.xxx:5555");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","vds");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "19");
    capabilities.setCapability("app-package", "air.iNMyBabyPaid"); //Replace with your app's package
    capabilities.setCapability("app-activity", "com.ripl.earlythree.activities.SplashActivty"); //Replace with app's Activity
    capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());

    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/"), capabilities);

    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);



     WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//EditText)[1]"));
      Assert.assertEquals("true", username.getAttribute("enabled"));

     if(username.isDisplayed())
     {

        username.click();

        username.sendKeys("sparent");

     }
     else
     {


         System.out.println("Your element not found");


     }


    driver.close();
   }

  }
```

When I run program , It just open App. in emulator and then stops.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Issue is resolved by correcting "app-package". I was using old app "app-package".